# Android Button Background

Tags: java, android, android-layout

i am new to android development, i am trying to create an application in which i use my own design for button for this i use background image for button, but when i put background image for button then it delete R.java file from  gen folder and show error in main activity R.layout.activity_main. Please help me i am very stress.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.ele.masjidddd.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:background="@drawable/timetablebtn"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my mainactivity xml code

Thanks

Comment: The R file is deleted when you add the android:background or when you add the file in your resources folder?

Comment: Only `a...z` (LOWER CASE), `0...9`, `.` and `_` are allowed for file names. And the file name cannot start with a number, nor contain spaces. But it's not your case, `android:background="@drawable/timetablebtn"`. So try restarting Eclipse after a Project/Clean.

Comment: GhodyDerfel, i do it through property section when i save it then R.java java is deleted

Comment: i tried to copy R.java file in my gen/packagefolder but when i clean my project then this file is deleted manually

Comment: Mr Frank N, Thank you very much i reviewed my hdpi folder and i found some file with upper case and when i changed their name my issue is resolved :D

Answer (score 0):

R.java is generated only automatically. If it's not in your gen folder, then you have a syntax error somewhere in your xml, most likely on the line you just added.